# Similarity between datasets A and B where B is a subset of A

Tags: clustering, similarities, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean

I have two datasets A and B, and for each entry in both datasets I have a mixture of ordered and unordered categorical variables such as gender, age (integral value) and date. It is believed that dataset B is a subset of dataset A, i.e. some of the entries in B in fact came from A, however with the possibility that the values might differ slightly, e.g. age +/- 1, or date being off by 2-3 days.

What I want to be able to do is to evaluate the similarity between the two dataset, and to verify that dataset B is indeed a subset of A. And if not, how much of dataset B is actually in dataset A?

Comment: Simply, it seems like you need to calculate the distance (of some sort) of each sample in B to A, and mark possible matches.

Comment: Besides the above matching based on the rectangular similarity matrix A x B, you could also do likewise hierarchical clustering of the complete square A+B similarity matrix with all entries between items of one and the same dataset set to zero. The similarity to compute could be Gower coefficient.